# does anyone know how to give a hint text in textFields in java(netbeans)?

Tags: java, netbeans

anyone know how to give a hint text in textField in java netbeans

eg: Text Field where user have to enter his Name i wanna give hidden text "name"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setToolTipText`

```
text1.setToolTipText("Hint");
```

Answer (score 0):

first set the text of the textfield to "Name".

```
private void jTextField2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
   jTextField2.setText(null);
}
```

After writing the above code and  clicking on the textfield the "Name" will disapper and u can enter your text.